# Publishing posts in WordPress using jwordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, posting

I am using *jwordpress-0.4.jar* to post to a WordPress installation.

The code I am using is:

```
Wordpress wp = new Wordpress(username, password, xmlRpcUrl);
Page recentPost = new Page();
recentPost.setPost_status("Published");
recentPost.setDescription("<ul>" + desc + "</ul>");
recentPost.setCategories(cat);
String pageID=recentPost.getPage_id();
String result = wp.newPost(recentPost, true);
```

This worked well before, but now when I go to publish it goes to its scheduling mode, 
I have tried:

> recentPost.setPost_status("Published");

and

> wp.newPost(recentPost, true);

But the post is still no published:

Comment: Did you check the xml that this helper generated for you? How does it differ from the API examples for Wordpress?

Comment: @Alessandro no, there is no any change from API Example.

Comment: I am using http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/source/browse/trunk/src/net/bican/wordpress/example/Main.java?spec=svn63&r=63 example

Comment: What is a 'cat' object you pass to setCategories(..) method?

Comment: Which version of WP are you testing against? Has it been recently upgraded? I know there is one problem with the 3.2.1 api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with different wordpress version. I have used the jwordpress-0.4.jar and it was working for me fine, don't remember which version if wordpress I was running it on though.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put:

```
recentPost.setPost_status("Published");
```

But use this instead:

```
recentPost.setPost_status("Publish");
```